# SED - address N lines before end of file

Tags: sed

Is there a simple way in `sed` to address a file, N lines before the end of the file?

For example, when trying to insert the contents of a file, I can easily insert *at* the end with `sed -i '$ r file2.txt' file1.txt`, and even right before the end with `sed -i -e '$ e cat file2.txt' file1.txt`, but can't seem to find a way to address some N number of lines *before* the end of the file. Something like `$-5` where 5 is the number lines.
I know there's probably some combination of `head` and `tail` one could use, but I'm looking for a purely `sed` way.

Comment: If you're working with a *file* (rather than a *stream*) you could consider using `ed` - in which it is possible ex. `printf '%s\n' '$-5r file2.txt' 'wq' | ed -s file1.txt`

Comment: What if the input file has less then 5 lines? For clarification, if the input file has say 6 lines, do you want to do something at line 1 or 2? Also, how big is the input file? One can use `-z` to read it entirely in pattern space, then copy it to hold space, delete last 5 lines, read second file, add back the last 5 lines from the hold space. Better methods still exist, awaiting your answers.

Comment: `sed` is the __stream__ editor, it cannot predict the end of the stream and cannot go backwards. So no, there's absolutely no "purely sed way". The `tac file | sed ... | tac` way from the answer is the most efficient you can get, at least with files with more than 50 lines or so.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to reverse the file, take the **first** N lines, then reverse the output of that

```bsh
$ seq 100 > file
$ tac file | sed -n 5,10p | tac
91
92
93
94
95
96
```

Comment: +1, but you miss the `'` in `sed` command`

Comment: Quotes are requiired by the shell to prevent [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)
and [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)
 -- there is nothing about the string `5,10p` that will trigger word splitting or globbing. So, I could probably add quotes, but they are not strictly required in this case.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i have tried your cmd (only the `sed` part) and it gave me an error. But if i try it at all it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, I don't know of a way to do this in one line with sed except maybe by carrying a large buffer, but with two lines this is possible more easily:

```
NUM_LINES=$((`sed -n $= file1.txt`-20))   # or however many lines you want instead of 20
sed -i "$NUM_LINES r file2.txt" file1.txt
```

Arguably it seems like you wanted to do it in one line, and potentially you could with a lot of `N;N;`s, but it's probably not very practical.